# Подключение класса в Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, gui

объявляю собственный класс в главном классе

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow.
```

вот так:  (буду вставлять немного лишнего, чтобы вы быстрее находили фрагменты)

```
private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
Control control;//собственно мой класс
```

Потом пытаюсь его использовать в реализации этого класса(при нажатии оно должно 
срабатывать):

```
void MainWindow::on_but_1_pressed(){
     ui->but_1->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: red;}");
     control.usrTurn(0);//вот здесь должна сработать функция
//и внести важные данные в объект класса.
}
```

Что за безобразие??:

- mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "`public: __cdecl Control::Control(void)`" (`??0Control@@QEAA@XZ`) в функции "`public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)`" (`??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z`)
- mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "`public: void __cdecl Control::usrTurn(int)`" (`?usrTurn@Control@@QEAAXH@Z`) в функции "`private: void __cdecl MainWindow::on_but_1_pressed(void)`" (`?on_but_1_pressed@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ`)

И говнокод собственной персоной:)

Мейн функция: (ничего интересного)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Объявление класса:

```
#ifndef CONTROL_H
#define CONTROL_H


class Control
{
    //для управления полем

    char game[8];

    //для создание игроков(присвоение х или о)
    const char O = 'O';
    const char X = 'X';

    void setGame(int index, char player);//установить значение в индекс
    void inPlay();//создать игроков/хрестик ходит первый
    char player_usr;
    char player_comp;
public:
    Control();
    char getUsr();
    char getComp();


    //game sector

    //char getGame(int index);//какое значение на месте index

    void usrTurn(int index);//пользователь ходит на индекс клетку
    void compTurn();//копмп ходит//ии


};

#endif // CONTROL_H
```

Реализация(класс недоделанный, некоторые функции не реализованы.  это не важно...):

```
#include "control.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include "Debag.h"//абсолютно рабочий
using namespace std;

Control::Control()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        game[i] = 'N';
    inPlay();

}


void Control::usrTurn(int index) {
    const char PLAYER = player_usr;

    setGame(index, PLAYER);
}

void Control::setGame(int index, char player)
{

    if (index < 0 || index > 8) {//ERROR_01
        log("01", "some problem whith index");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (game->GetValue(index) == 'N') {
        game[index] = player;
    }
    else {//ERROR_02
         log("02", "There no empty place (ControlPros.cpp)");
         exit(1);
    }
}


 void Control::inPlay() {
    srand(time(0));
    (rand() % 2);

    if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
         player_usr = X;
         player_comp = O;
    }
    else {
        player_usr = O;
        player_comp = X;
    }
}

char Control::getUsr() { return player_usr; }
char Control::getComp() { return player_comp; }
```

Думаю, там всё работает как надо, что-то не так в Qt классах:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include<control.h>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void on_but_1_pressed();
    void on_but_1_released();

    void on_but_2_pressed();
    void on_but_2_released();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Control control;// я пытаюсь объявить класс
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Вот здесь я пытаюсь его применить:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{


    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->but_1->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: blue;}");
    ui->but_2->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: blue;}");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_but_1_pressed(){
     ui->but_1->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: red;}");
     control.usrTurn(0);//вот здесь я пытаюсь его использовать
}
void MainWindow::on_but_1_released(){
   ui->but_1->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: blue;}");

}

void MainWindow::on_but_2_pressed(){
    ui->but_2->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: red;}");
}

void MainWindow::on_but_2_released(){
    ui->but_2->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color: blue;}");
}
```

Comment: Сколько я помню, это связано с отсутствием библиотек/dll. Когда-то сам сталкивался с подобным, но это было давно, так что чего-то более конструктивного сказать не могу.

Comment: Плюсы уже подзабыл, но конструкция `namespace Ui { class MainWindow; } class MainWindow : public QMainWindow { }` доверия не внушает. И `#include<control.h>` тоже. Попробуйте упростить пространства имён (убрать все) и файлы (запихать всё в одну пару h+cpp), плюс нормальные названия классам не помешало бы дать. Если всё заработает, будет исходная точка, от которой можно двигаться в правильном направлении.

Comment: @Squidward, здесь у автора с namespace'ами всё в порядке. Ругается линковщик. Правильная сборка поможет.

Comment: много кода, может лучше было залить проект на гитхаб?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как только компилятор начинает матюкаться на сигналы и слоты (у нас матюкается на тела слотов), повторяем мантру:

Сборка -> Очистить проект

Сборка -> Запустить qmake

Сборка -> Собрать

Объяснение такое - где-то поломался `moc`, его надо спасти. Кто такой `moc` - читайте у Шлее

Answer (score 5):

У вас линковщик ругается. Нужно:

- проверить добавлены ли ваши файлы `control.h` и `control.cpp` в соответствующие секции (`HEADERS` и `SOURCES`) `.pro`-файла;
- удалить, если существует, объектный файл `control.obj` (да и все другие `.obj` заодно);
- пересобрать программу: последовательно запустить `qmake` и `make` (или `mingw`, или что там у вас вместо него); или из вашей IDE - Сборка -> Собрать проект.